# How to get ID of specific document in subcollection?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get ID of document in Reservations collection. I don't know ho to do that. When I want to overwrite data in specific Reservation it can't because I don't have ID of the reservation. I am putting their UID of user that is wrong.

```
 guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let userCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("Users")
    let thisUserDoc = userCollection.document(uid)

    let snapshot = thisUserDoc.collection("Reservations").document(uid).updateData(data) { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error updating document: \(err) ")
        }
        else {
            print("Document successfully updated")
        }
    }
```

[Error message - wrong path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j19Wf.png)
[Database scructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSimD.png)

Answer (score 1):

As shown in your code and in the error shared in your question you use the same document ID for the doc in the `users` collection and for the doc in the `Reservations` (sub)collection. The database screenshot shows that it cannot work: there isn’t any doc corresponding to this case.

You need to use an existing ID for the doc in the `Reservations` (sub)collection.

If you don’t know the desired ID you can maybe build a query based on some specific field(s) of the doc.

Comment: Yeah I know. Problem is that I don't know how can I get ID of specific Reservation.

Comment: Do you want to get a specific reservation or all the reservations for a user? If you want to get a specific reservation you need to have a way to identify it from its data. Example: the most recent one OR the reservation with field `abcd` = `efgh`…

Comment: It is possible to save document ID to reservation and then identify it by it ?

Comment: Yes but if you know the if you don’t need to save it in the document. Maybe you should explain in more detail your exact requirement. It will be easier to help you. You can modify your question and ask more details

Comment: *if you know the ID

Comment: The whole problem is to get the ID of reservation in collection Reservation everything other is okay :D. I am really traying to get it but with no success.

Comment: @BranislavFekeč I cannot help you if you just say "I am really trying to get it but with no success.". What is the **functional/business** logic to find the document? As I said above if you don't explain in more detail your exact global requirement it is impossible to help you furthermore. What is the logic to create and find a reservation?